# cypress: expect element contains some text

Tags: cypress

I want to check second `.item` element contains some text

```
cy.get('.item').then(($items) => {
  expect($items).to.have.length(2);
  expect($items[1]).to.contain('Published');
});
```

cypress throw error: `TypeError: obj.is is not a function`.

I also tried `expect($items[1]).text.to.contain('Published');`
this time error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'contain' of undefined`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it has no problems with `$items`, your issue is in the array you expect with `$items[1]`. As Cypress states, $items[1] is undefined and the 'is not a function' error is the same issue but described more complex :). So Cypress could not find a second element and therefor working with an Array doesn't work. It will probably pass if you change it to this:

```js
cy.get('.item').then(($items) => {
  expect($items).to.have.length(2);
  expect($items).to.contain('Published');
});
```

You could also check for the specific element in a completely different way:

```js
cy.get('.item')
  .eq(2)
  .should('contain', 'Published')
```

That results in retrieving the second 'item' and checking if it contains 'Published'. And of course you can change the eq() to a higher or lower number

Comment: is there a way to check a particular item in `$items`?